# Jupyterlab notebook cell becomes white, no brackets, no output, kernel idle

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

[image]
(Note: everything works in the normal Python repl)  As I "walk" through my cells using `shift+enter`, I arrive at one that loses its gray background when I execute it.  Its background becomes white, the font in its text changes, and no brackets appear on the left to indicate execution order or even busy kernel.  Everything just... seems to stop.  This state persists after I restart the kernel.  I can click into the cell manually, then press escape, and this will get the gray background and proper font to return, but executing brings things back to the "broken" state.

[image]
As can be seen in the second figure, this "broken" state happens in all of the subsequent cells, except for my `who` call, which seems to work.  This is a small ocean model that does take a little time to run.  But the initial "configure" call shouldn't take very long, and, furthermore, why would I not get a `[*]` if things were still running?  The next line actually runs the model, so I do expect that to take a little time.  But the problem seems to start before that.

Could this have to do with how I installed things?  I have been using Conda, but, to get the ocean model installed, I followed instructions and installed Mamba.  I just plopped it on top of everything, without deleting miniconda.  I also uses Mamba to install Jupyterlab.

What might be going on?

Comment: Did you accidentally change the cell type to markdown?

Comment: There is cell type switch on the toolbar

Comment: thanks, that did it.